# Golang crypto library: security

Tags: cryptography, go

I've recently put together a library for working with Crypto in Go.

I did not roll my own, I'm relying on stdlib for the core parts of this, but I would still like to get this reviewed by some experts in case I've done something horrific.

If you're interested and want to view this in a more palatable format, you can find it here: https://github.com/alistanis/goenc

All of my tests currently pass and everything is working as expected.

I really appreciate the time that anyone is willing to spend on this, so thanks in advance.

**The Code**

*enc.go*

```
// Package goenc contains functions for working with encryption
package goenc

// work is derived from many sources:
//
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151714/go-generate-an-ssh-public-key
// https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/
// https://leanpub.com/gocrypto/read#leanpub-auto-aes-cbc
// https://github.com/hashicorp/memberlist/blob/master/security.go

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/binary"
    "io"

    "io/ioutil"

    "os"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/aes/cbc"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/aes/cfb"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/aes/ctr"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/aes/gcm"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/encerrors"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/nacl"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt"
)

/*
    TODO(cmc): Verify this isn't horrifically insecure and have this reviewed by a(n) expert(s) before publishing
*/

// BlockCipher represents a cipher that encodes and decodes chunks of data at a time
type BlockCipher interface {
    Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error)
    Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error)
    KeySize() int
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BlockCipherInterface Functions - these should not be used with large files
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// EncryptAndSaveWithPerms encrypts data and saves it to a file with the given permissions using the given key
func EncryptAndSaveWithPerms(cipher BlockCipher, key, plaintext []byte, path string, perm os.FileMode) error {
    data, err := cipher.Encrypt(key, plaintext)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return ioutil.WriteFile(path, data, perm)
}

// EncryptAndSave encrypts data and saves it to a file with the permissions 0644
func EncryptAndSave(cipher BlockCipher, key, plaintext []byte, path string) error {
    return EncryptAndSaveWithPerms(cipher, key, plaintext, path, 0644)
}

// ReadEncryptedFile reads a file a path and attempts to decrypt the data there with the given key
func ReadEncryptedFile(cipher BlockCipher, key []byte, path string) ([]byte, error) {
    ciphertext, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    plaintext, err := cipher.Decrypt(key, ciphertext)
    return plaintext, err
}

// CipherKind represents what kind of cipher to use
type CipherKind int

// CipherKind constants
const (
    CBC CipherKind = iota
    CFB
    CTR
    GCM
    NaCL

    Mock
)

const (
    // SaltSize sets a generic salt size
    SaltSize = 64
)

// Cipher is a struct that contains a BlockCipher interface and stores a DerivedKey Complexity number
type Cipher struct {
    BlockCipher
    DerivedKeyN int
}

// NewCipher returns a new Cipher containing a BlockCipher interface based on the CipherKind
func NewCipher(kind CipherKind, derivedKeyN int, args ...[]byte) (*Cipher, error) {
    c := &Cipher{DerivedKeyN: derivedKeyN}
    switch kind {
    case GCM:
        c.BlockCipher = gcm.New()
    case NaCL:
        // special case, we need to define a pad for nacl
        if len(args) == 0 {
            return nil, encerrors.ErrNoPadProvided
        }
        n := &nacl.Cipher{}
        n.Pad = args[0]
        c.BlockCipher = n
    case CFB:
        c.BlockCipher = cfb.New()
    case CBC:
        c.BlockCipher = cbc.New()
    case CTR:
        c.BlockCipher = ctr.New()
    case Mock:
        c.BlockCipher = &MockBlockCipher{}
    default:
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidCipherKind
    }
    return c, nil
}

// Encrypt takes a password, plaintext, and derives a key based on that password,
// then encrypting that data with the underlying block cipher
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(password, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    salt, err := generate.RandBytes(SaltSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    key, err := DeriveKey(password, salt, c.DerivedKeyN, c.BlockCipher.KeySize())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    out, err := c.BlockCipher.Encrypt(key, plaintext)
    Zero(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    out = append(salt, out...)
    return out, nil
}

// Overhead is the amount of Overhead contained in the ciphertext
const Overhead = SaltSize + secretbox.Overhead + generate.NonceSize

// Decrypt takes a password and ciphertext, derives a key, and attempts to decrypt that data
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(password, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(ciphertext) < Overhead {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    key, err := DeriveKey(password, ciphertext[:SaltSize], c.DerivedKeyN, c.KeySize())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    out, err := c.BlockCipher.Decrypt(key, ciphertext[SaltSize:])
    Zero(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return out, nil
}

// MockBlockCipher implements BlockCipher but does nothing
type MockBlockCipher struct{}

// Encrypt in this case is only implementing the BlockCipher interface, it doesn't do anything
func (m *MockBlockCipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return plaintext, nil
}

// Decrypt in this case is only implementing the BlockCipher interface, it doesn't do anything
func (m *MockBlockCipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return ciphertext, nil
}

// KeySize is a mock key size to use with the mock cipher
func (m *MockBlockCipher) KeySize() int {
    return 32
}

// Message represents a message being passed, and contains its contents and a sequence number
type Message struct {
    Number   uint32
    Contents []byte
}

// NewMessage returns a new message
func NewMessage(in []byte, num uint32) *Message {
    return &Message{Contents: in, Number: num}
}

// Marshal encodes a sequence number into the data that we wish to send
func (m *Message) Marshal() []byte {
    out := make([]byte, 4, len(m.Contents)+4)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(out[:4], m.Number)
    return append(out, m.Contents...)
}

// UnmarshalMessage decodes bytes into a message pointer
func UnmarshalMessage(in []byte) (*Message, error) {
    m := &Message{}
    if len(in) <= 4 {
        return m, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    m.Number = binary.BigEndian.Uint32(in[:4])
    m.Contents = in[4:]
    return m, nil
}

// Channel is a typed io.ReadWriter used for communicating securely
type Channel io.ReadWriter

// Session represents a session that can be used to pass messages over a secure channel
type Session struct {
    Cipher *Cipher
    Channel
    lastSent uint32
    lastRecv uint32
    sendKey  *[32]byte
    recvKey  *[32]byte
}

// LastSent returns the last sent message id
func (s *Session) LastSent() uint32 {
    return s.lastSent
}

// LastRecv returns the last received message id
func (s *Session) LastRecv() uint32 {
    return s.lastRecv
}

// Encrypt encrypts a message with an embedded message id
func (s *Session) Encrypt(message []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(message) == 0 {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    s.lastSent++
    m := NewMessage(message, s.lastSent)
    return s.Cipher.Encrypt(s.sendKey[:], m.Marshal())
}

// Decrypt decrypts a message and checks that its message id is valid
func (s *Session) Decrypt(message []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    out, err := s.Cipher.Decrypt(s.recvKey[:], message)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    m, err := UnmarshalMessage(out)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // if this number is less than or equal to the last received message, this is a replay and we bail
    if m.Number <= s.lastRecv {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageID
    }

    s.lastRecv = m.Number

    return m.Contents, nil
}

// Send encrypts the message and sends it out over the channel.
func (s *Session) Send(message []byte) error {
    m, err := s.Encrypt(message)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = binary.Write(s.Channel, binary.BigEndian, uint32(len(m)))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = s.Channel.Write(m)
    return err
}

// Receive listens for a new message on the channel.
func (s *Session) Receive() ([]byte, error) {
    var mlen uint32
    err := binary.Read(s.Channel, binary.BigEndian, &mlen)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    message := make([]byte, int(mlen))
    _, err = io.ReadFull(s.Channel, message)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return s.Decrypt(message)
}

// GenerateKeyPair generates a new key pair. This can be used to get a
// new key pair for setting up a rekeying operation during the session.
func GenerateKeyPair() (pub *[64]byte, priv *[64]byte, err error) {
    pub = new([64]byte)
    priv = new([64]byte)

    recvPub, recvPriv, err := box.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    copy(pub[:], recvPub[:])
    copy(priv[:], recvPriv[:])

    sendPub, sendPriv, err := box.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    copy(pub[32:], sendPub[:])
    copy(priv[32:], sendPriv[:])
    return pub, priv, err
}

// Close zeroises the keys in the session. Once a session is closed,
// the traffic that was sent over the channel can no longer be decrypted
// and any attempts at sending or receiving messages over the channel
// will fail.
func (s *Session) Close() error {
    Zero(s.sendKey[:])
    Zero(s.recvKey[:])
    return nil
}

// keyExchange is a convenience function that takes keys as byte slices,
// copying them into the appropriate arrays.
func keyExchange(shared *[32]byte, priv, pub []byte) {
    // Copy the private key and wipe it, as it will no longer be needed.
    var kexPriv [32]byte
    copy(kexPriv[:], priv)
    Zero(priv)

    var kexPub [32]byte
    copy(kexPub[:], pub)

    box.Precompute(shared, &kexPub, &kexPriv)
    Zero(kexPriv[:])
}

// NewSession returns a new *Session
func NewSession(ch Channel, c *Cipher) *Session {
    return &Session{
        Cipher:  c,
        Channel: ch,
        recvKey: new([32]byte),
        sendKey: new([32]byte),
    }
}

// Dial sets up a new session over the channel by generating a new pair
// of Curve25519 keypairs, sending its public keys to the peer, and
// reading the peer's public keys back.
func Dial(ch Channel, c *Cipher) (*Session, error) {
    var peer [64]byte
    pub, priv, err := GenerateKeyPair()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = ch.Write(pub[:])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Make sure the entire public key is read.
    _, err = io.ReadFull(ch, peer[:])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    s := NewSession(ch, c)

    s.KeyExchange(priv, &peer, true)
    return s, nil
}

// Listen waits for a peer to Dial in, then sets up a key exchange
// and session.
func Listen(ch Channel, c *Cipher) (*Session, error) {
    var peer [64]byte
    pub, priv, err := GenerateKeyPair()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Ensure the entire peer key is read.
    _, err = io.ReadFull(ch, peer[:])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = ch.Write(pub[:])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    s := NewSession(ch, c)

    s.KeyExchange(priv, &peer, false)
    return s, nil
}

// KeyExchange - Rekey is used to perform the key exchange once both sides have
// exchanged their public keys. The underlying message protocol will
// need to actually initiate and carry out the key exchange, and call
// this once that is finished. The private key will be zeroised after
// calling this function. If the session is on the side that initiated
// the key exchange (e.g. by calling Dial), it should set the dialer
// argument to true. This will also reset the message counters for the
// session, as it will cause the session to use a new key.
func (s *Session) KeyExchange(priv, peer *[64]byte, dialer bool) {
    // This function denotes the dialer, who initiates the session,
    // as A. The listener is denoted as B. A is started using Dial,
    // and B is started using Listen.
    if dialer {
        // The first 32 bytes are the A->B link, where A is the
        // dialer. This key material should be used to set up the
        // A send key.
        keyExchange(s.sendKey, priv[:32], peer[:32])

        // The last 32 bytes are the B->A link, where A is the
        // dialer. This key material should be used to set up the A
        // receive key.
        keyExchange(s.recvKey, priv[32:], peer[32:])
    } else {
        // The first 32 bytes are the A->B link, where A is the
        // dialer. This key material should be used to set up the
        // B receive key.
        keyExchange(s.recvKey, priv[:32], peer[:32])

        // The last 32 bytes are the B->A link, where A is the
        // dialer. This key material should be used to set up the
        // B send key.
        keyExchange(s.sendKey, priv[32:], peer[32:])
    }
    s.lastSent = 0
    s.lastRecv = 0
}

const (
    // testComplexity is unexported because we don't want to use such a weak key in the wild
    testComplexity = 1 << (iota + 7)
)

const (
    // N Complexity in powers of 2 for key Derivation

    // InteractiveComplexity - recommended complexity for interactive sessions
    InteractiveComplexity = 1 << (iota + 14)
    // Complexity15 is 2^15
    Complexity15
    // Complexity16 is 2^16
    Complexity16
    // Complexity17 is 2^17
    Complexity17
    // Complexity18 is 2^18
    Complexity18
    // Complexity19 is 2^19
    Complexity19
    // AggressiveComplexity is 2^20 (don't use this unless you have incredibly strong CPU power
    AggressiveComplexity
)

// DeriveKey generates a new NaCl key from a passphrase and salt.
// This is a costly operation.
func DeriveKey(pass, salt []byte, N, keySize int) ([]byte, error) {
    var naclKey = make([]byte, keySize)
    key, err := scrypt.Key(pass, salt, N, 8, 1, keySize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    copy(naclKey, key)
    Zero(key)
    return naclKey, nil
}

// Zero zeroes out bytes of data so that it does not stay in memory any longer than necessary
func Zero(data []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        data[i] = 0
    }
}
```

*aes/cbc/cbc.go*

```
// Package cbc supports cbc encryption
package cbc

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"

    "io"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/encerrors"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
)

const (
    // NonceSize to use for nonces
    NonceSize = aes.BlockSize
    // MACSize is the output size of HMAC-SHA-256
    MACSize = 32
    // CKeySize - Cipher key size - AES-256
    CKeySize = 32
    // MKeySize - HMAC key size - HMAC-SHA-256
    MKeySize = 32
    // KeySize is the key size for CBC
    KeySize = CKeySize + MKeySize
)

// pad pads input to match the correct size
func pad(in []byte) []byte {
    padding := 16 - (len(in) % 16)
    for i := 0; i < padding; i++ {
        in = append(in, byte(padding))
    }
    return in
}

// unpad removes unnecessary bytes that were added during initial padding
func unpad(in []byte) []byte {
    if len(in) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    padding := in[len(in)-1]
    if int(padding) > len(in) || padding > aes.BlockSize {
        return nil
    } else if padding == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    for i := len(in) - 1; i > len(in)-int(padding)-1; i-- {
        if in[i] != padding {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return in[:len(in)-int(padding)]
}

// Cipher implements the BlockCipher interface
type Cipher struct{}

// Encrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Encrypt(key, plaintext)
}

// Decrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Decrypt(key, ciphertext)
}

// KeySize returns CBC KeySize and implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) KeySize() int {
    return KeySize
}

// New returns a new cbc cipher
func New() *Cipher {
    return &Cipher{}
}

// Key returns a random key as a pointer to an array of bytes specified by KeySize
func Key() (*[KeySize]byte, error) {
    key := new([KeySize]byte)
    _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, key[:])
    return key, err
}

// Encrypt encrypts plaintext using the given key with CBC encryption
func Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(key) != KeySize {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidKeyLength
    }

    iv, err := generate.RandBytes(NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pmessage := pad(plaintext)
    ct := make([]byte, len(pmessage))

    // NewCipher only returns an error with an invalid key size,
    // but the key size was checked at the beginning of the function.
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key[:CKeySize])
    ctr := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(c, iv)
    ctr.CryptBlocks(ct, pmessage)

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key[CKeySize:])
    ct = append(iv, ct...)
    h.Write(ct)
    ct = h.Sum(ct)
    return ct, nil
}

// Decrypt decrypts ciphertext using the given key
func Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(key) != KeySize {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidKeyLength
    }

    // HMAC-SHA-256 returns a MAC that is also a multiple of the
    // block size.
    if (len(ciphertext) % aes.BlockSize) != 0 {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    // A ciphertext must have at least an IV block, a ciphertext block,
    // and two blocks of HMAC.
    if len(ciphertext) < (4 * aes.BlockSize) {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    macStart := len(ciphertext) - MACSize
    tag := ciphertext[macStart:]
    out := make([]byte, macStart-NonceSize)
    ciphertext = ciphertext[:macStart]

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key[CKeySize:])
    h.Write(ciphertext)
    mac := h.Sum(nil)
    if !hmac.Equal(mac, tag) {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidSum
    }

    // NewCipher only returns an error with an invalid key size,
    // but the key size was checked at the beginning of the function.
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key[:CKeySize])
    ctr := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(c, ciphertext[:NonceSize])
    ctr.CryptBlocks(out, ciphertext[NonceSize:])

    pt := unpad(out)
    if pt == nil {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidPadding
    }

    return pt, nil
}
```

*aes/cfb/cfb.go*

```
// Package cfb supports basic cfb encryption with NO HMAC
package cfb

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "io"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/encerrors"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
)

// KeySize for CFB uses the generic key size
const KeySize = generate.KeySize

// Cipher to use for implementing the BlockCipher interface
type Cipher struct {
}

// New returns a new cfb cipher
func New() *Cipher {
    return &Cipher{}
}

// Encrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Encrypt(key, plaintext)
}

// Decrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Decrypt(key, ciphertext)
}

// KeySize implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) KeySize() int {
    return KeySize
}

// Decrypt decrypts ciphertext using the given key
func Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    // Create the AES cipher
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    // get first 16 bytes from ciphertext
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]

    // Remove the IV from the ciphertext
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]

    // Return a decrypted stream
    stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)

    // SimpleDecrypt bytes from ciphertext
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, ciphertext)

    return ciphertext, nil
}

// Encrypt encrypts ciphertext using the given key.
// NOTE: This is not secure without being authenticated (crypto/hmac)
func Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // Create the AES cipher
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Empty array of 16 + plaintext length
    // Include the IV at the beginning
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))

    // Slice of first 16 bytes
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]

    // Write 16 rand bytes to fill iv
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Return an encrypted stream
    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)

    // SimpleEncrypt bytes from plaintext to ciphertext
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)
    return ciphertext, nil
}

// DecryptString decrypts ciphertext using the given key
func DecryptString(key, ciphertext string) (string, error) {
    b, err := Decrypt([]byte(key), []byte(ciphertext))
    return string(b), err
}

// EncryptString encrypts ciphertext using the given key
func EncryptString(key, plaintext string) (string, error) {
    b, err := Encrypt([]byte(key), []byte(plaintext))
    return string(b), err
}
```

*aes/ctr/ctr.go*

```
// Package ctr supports ctr encryption
package ctr

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"

    "io"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/encerrors"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
)

const (
    // NonceSize to use for nonces
    NonceSize = aes.BlockSize
    // MACSize is the output size of HMAC-SHA-256
    MACSize = 32
    // CKeySize - Cipher key size - AES-256
    CKeySize = 32
    // MKeySize - HMAC key size - HMAC-SHA-256
    MKeySize = 32
    // KeySize to use for keys, 64 bytes
    KeySize = CKeySize + MKeySize
)

// Cipher to implement the BlockCipher interface
type Cipher struct {
}

// New returns a new ctr cipher
func New() *Cipher {
    return &Cipher{}
}

// Encrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Encrypt(key, plaintext)
}

// Decrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Decrypt(key, ciphertext)
}

// KeySize implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) KeySize() int {
    return KeySize
}

// Key returns a pointer to an array of bytes with the given KeySize
func Key() (*[KeySize]byte, error) {
    key := new([KeySize]byte)
    _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, key[:])
    return key, err
}

// Encrypt encrypts plaintext using the given key with CTR encryption
func Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(key) != KeySize {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidKeyLength
    }

    nonce, err := generate.RandBytes(NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    ct := make([]byte, len(plaintext))

    // NewCipher only returns an error with an invalid key size,
    // but the key size was checked at the beginning of the function.
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key[:CKeySize])
    ctr := cipher.NewCTR(c, nonce)
    ctr.XORKeyStream(ct, plaintext)

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key[CKeySize:])
    ct = append(nonce, ct...)
    h.Write(ct)
    ct = h.Sum(ct)
    return ct, nil
}

// Decrypt decrypts ciphertext using the given key
func Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(key) != KeySize {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidKeyLength
    }

    if len(ciphertext) <= (NonceSize + MACSize) {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    macStart := len(ciphertext) - MACSize
    tag := ciphertext[macStart:]
    out := make([]byte, macStart-NonceSize)
    ciphertext = ciphertext[:macStart]

    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key[CKeySize:])
    h.Write(ciphertext)
    mac := h.Sum(nil)
    if !hmac.Equal(mac, tag) {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidSum
    }

    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key[:CKeySize])
    ctr := cipher.NewCTR(c, ciphertext[:NonceSize])
    ctr.XORKeyStream(out, ciphertext[NonceSize:])
    return out, nil
}
```

*aes/gcm/gcm.go*

```
// Package gcm supports gcm encryption
package gcm

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/binary"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/encerrors"
    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
)

// NonceSize // generic NonceSize
const NonceSize = generate.NonceSize

// KeySize // generic KeySize
const KeySize = generate.KeySize

// Cipher to implement the BlockCipher interface
type Cipher struct {
}

// New returns a new GCM cipher
func New() *Cipher {
    return &Cipher{}
}

// Encrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Encrypt(key, plaintext)
}

// Decrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Decrypt(key, ciphertext)
}

// KeySize returns the GCM key size
func (c *Cipher) KeySize() int {
    return KeySize
}

// Encrypt secures a message using AES-GCM.
func Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(c, NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    nonce, err := generate.Nonce()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Seal will append the output to the first argument; the usage
    // here appends the ciphertext to the nonce. The final parameter
    // is any additional data to be authenticated.
    out := gcm.Seal(nonce[:], nonce[:], plaintext, nil)
    return out, nil
}

// EncryptString is a convenience function for working with strings
func EncryptString(key, plaintext string) (string, error) {
    data, err := Encrypt([]byte(key), []byte(plaintext))
    return string(data), err
}

// Decrypt decrypts data using AES-GCM
func Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // Create the AES cipher
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(block, NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    nonce := make([]byte, NonceSize)
    copy(nonce, ciphertext)
    return gcm.Open(nil, nonce[:], ciphertext[NonceSize:], nil)
}

// DecryptString is a convenience function for working with strings
func DecryptString(key, ciphertext string) (string, error) {
    data, err := Decrypt([]byte(key), []byte(ciphertext))
    return string(data), err
}

//---------------------------------------------
// For use with more complex encryption schemes
//---------------------------------------------

// EncryptWithID secures a message and prepends a 4-byte sender ID
// to the message. The end bit is tricky, because gcm.Seal modifies buf, and this is necessary
func EncryptWithID(key, message []byte, sender uint32) ([]byte, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buf, sender)

    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(c, NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    nonce, err := generate.Nonce()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    buf = append(buf, nonce[:]...)
    return gcm.Seal(buf, nonce[:], message, buf[:4]), nil
}

// EncryptStringWithID is a helper function to work with strings instead of bytes
func EncryptStringWithID(key, message string, sender uint32) (string, error) {
    data, err := EncryptWithID([]byte(key), []byte(message), sender)
    return string(data), err
}

// DecryptWithID takes an encrypted message and a KeyForID function (to get a key from a cache or a database perhaps)
// It checks the first 4 bytes for prepended header data, in this case, a sender ID
func DecryptWithID(message []byte, k KeyRetriever) ([]byte, error) {

    if len(message) <= NonceSize+4 {
        return nil, encerrors.ErrInvalidMessageLength
    }

    id := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(message[:4])
    key, err := k.KeyForID(id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(c, NonceSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    nonce := make([]byte, NonceSize)
    copy(nonce, message[4:])

    ciphertext := message[4+NonceSize:]

    // Decrypt the message, using the sender ID as the additional
    // data requiring authentication.
    out, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertext, message[:4])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return out, nil
}

// DecryptStringWithID is a helper function to work with strings instead of bytes
func DecryptStringWithID(message string, k KeyRetriever) (string, error) {
    data, err := DecryptWithID([]byte(message), k)
    return string(data), err
}

// KeyRetriever represents a type that should be used in order to retrieve a key from a datastore
type KeyRetriever interface {
    KeyForID(uint32) ([]byte, error)
}

// GCMHelper is designed to make it easy to call EncryptWithID and DecryptWithID by assigning the KeyForIDFunc
// it implements KeyRetriever and provides convenience functions
// It also serves as an example for how to use KeyRetriever
type GCMHelper struct {
    KeyForIDFunc func(uint32) ([]byte, error)
}

// NewGCMHelper returns a new helper
func NewGCMHelper(f func(uint32) ([]byte, error)) *GCMHelper {
    return &GCMHelper{f}
}

// KeyForID implements the KeyRetriever interface, it should be used to get a Key for the given ID
func (h *GCMHelper) KeyForID(u uint32) ([]byte, error) {
    return h.KeyForIDFunc(u)
}
```

*nacl/nacl.go*

```
// Package nacl provides encryption by salting a key with a pad
package nacl

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software)
// work is derived from:
//
// https://github.com/andmarios/golang-nacl-secretbox

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/alistanis/goenc/generate"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox"
)

const (
    keySize   = 32
    nonceSize = 24
)

// Cipher to implmement the BlockCipher interface
type Cipher struct {
    Pad []byte
}

// Encrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Encrypt(key, plaintext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Encrypt(c.Pad, key, plaintext)
}

// Decrypt implements the BlockCipher interface
func (c *Cipher) Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return Decrypt(c.Pad, key, ciphertext)
}

// KeySize returns the NaCL keysize
func (c *Cipher) KeySize() int {
    return keySize
}

// Encrypt salts a key using pad and encrypts a message
func Encrypt(pad, key, message []byte) (out []byte, err error) {
    if len(pad) < 32 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("pad had a length of %d, it must be at least 32 bytes", len(pad))
    }
    // NaCl's key has a constant size of 32 bytes.
    // The user provided key probably is less than that. We pad it with
    // a long enough string and truncate anything we don't need later on.
    key = append(key, pad...)

    // NaCl's key should be of type [32]byte.
    // Here we create it and truncate key bytes beyond 32
    naclKey := new([keySize]byte)
    copy(naclKey[:], key[:keySize])

    nonce, err := generate.Nonce()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // out will hold the nonce and the encrypted message (ciphertext)
    out = make([]byte, nonceSize)
    // Copy the nonce to the start of out
    copy(out, nonce[:])
    // SimpleEncrypt the message and append it to out, assign the result to out
    out = secretbox.Seal(out, message, nonce, naclKey)
    return out, err
}

// Decrypt salts a key using pad and decrypts a message
func Decrypt(pad, key, data []byte) (out []byte, err error) {
    key = append(key, pad...)

    // NaCl's key should be of type [32]byte.
    // Here we create it and truncate key bytes beyond 32
    naclKey := new([keySize]byte)
    copy(naclKey[:], key[:keySize])

    // The nonce is of type [24]byte and part of the data we will receive
    nonce := new([nonceSize]byte)

    // Read the nonce from in, it is in the first 24 bytes
    copy(nonce[:], data[:nonceSize])

    // SimpleDecrypt the output of secretbox.Seal which contains the nonce and
    // the encrypted message
    message, ok := secretbox.Open(nil, data[nonceSize:], nonce, naclKey)
    if ok {
        return message, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Decryption failed")
}

// RandomPadEncrypt generates a random pad and returns the encrypted data, the pad, and an error if any
func RandomPadEncrypt(key, message []byte) (pad, out []byte, err error) {
    pad = make([]byte, 32)
    _, err = rand.Read(pad)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    out, err = Encrypt(pad, key, message)
    return
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you say you aren't rolling your own crypto, but you're creating your own crypto library.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't there *other* crypto libs already out there that have had a lot more vetting from a security perspective?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The core golang stdlib implements the real meat of the crypto, but it's still hard for people to use and understand without a lot of research. The only other library I'm aware of that does anything similar is https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta, but (maybe rightly) does not provide examples for anything other than gcm. If there are other libraries out there I'm happy to defer to those as well.

Additionally, mine implements a standard interface, so at some point, if GCM is broken and a new standard is introduced, it would be trivial to reuse existing code.

Answer (score 6):

The code in the question shows a CBC wrapper class. However, that wrapper class uses HMAC for authentication, without this being apparent in the name of the class. Having authenticated ciphertext is great, but if it is present then that should be made clear. Another design mistake is making the mode of operation part of the `BlockCipher` interface. That is the wrong way around: a mode of operation **uses a block cipher** as configuration parameter. A block cipher does not include a HMAC.

HMAC authentication is also implemented for CTR mode. CTR mode has many uses for specialized encryption constructs. For instance, CTR mode is used in GCM, CCM and EAX modes of operation. However, those do of course not use HMAC. Inexplicably, the HMAC authentication is not implemented for the old CFB mode that, which, although secure, is generally not used in new protocols. It also means that the API is not symmetric; CBC and CTR do have HMAC authentication, why is CFB left behind?

Fortunately the code uses encrypt-then-MAC, which is the correct order.

---

The code contains functionality perform transport security and - what I presume is - in place encryption using passwords. That means it tries t do multiple things at the same time. Cryptography related code should be written with a specific use case in mind. Generic crypto code should be a very well written API so it can be used for those kind of use cases, and this is not it.

The transport mode security seems to contain key agreement but not authentication. There doesn't seem to be any warning about this in the comments.

---

The idea keys supplied by the user needs padding is very dangerous. It lets users believe that their key is secure, while it should be either 16, 24 or 32 fully random bytes for AES. Generally passwords should not be treated as keys. It is possible to turn passwords into keys using a PBKDF2, although for encryption password should be avoided where possible.

---

In general I'd warn against using "wrapper" classes, that are created to make AES "easy". It takes a very significant amount of time to remove a wrapper class from a code base. I've spend many hours trying to remove a self-spun wrapper class, mimicking a C++ wrapper class in Java.

You have been warned; don't make the same mistake that I did.